# PHP sign up form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP so I have trouble with make simple sign up form. My issue is that when I would like to sign up every data is send to my db except password. Where is the error?

My db is mySQL. Try few times user_pwd has no output in my db...

php singup form:

```
<form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Surname">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="ID">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Sing up</button>
        </form>
```

php - singup.inc.php:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once 'db.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);
    // error handlers
    // all fields not empty
    if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd) ){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        // check spelling
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-z]*$/", $last)){
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
        exit();
        }
        else{
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
        exit();
            }
            else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($resultCheck>0){
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    exit();
                }else{
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFALUT);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: echo the $sql string before input into database.

Comment: INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('piotr', 'miroddc', 'pssld@wp.pl', 'lolek', '');  last output is empty..

Comment: if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
  {
      echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  }

Comment: i try echo pwd and hashedpwd, so pwd have a output where hashed not.

Comment: If you had error checking on `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` you would notice the errors and warnings.

Comment: You should also look into prepared statements and bind variables as you are open to SQL injection issues etc.

Comment: Your regex validation of the first/last names might also cause you some issues in the future. People can have dashes or hyphens as part of their names, which you do no account for in the regex, plus escaping both values before validating might also introduce escape characters that the regex also wouldn't allow in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> Return Values ¶
>
> Returns the hashed password, or FALSE on failure.

you have

```
$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFALUT);
```

which most likely returns "false", because it doesn't support the hash mode "PASSWORD_DEFALUT".

Try editing that to the correct format

```
$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

I hope that solves it for you.

Comment: $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFALUT);  and  $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  they are the same... so what schould i edit?

Comment: DEFA->LU<-T is not quite the same as DEFAULT. It's a simple spelling error as far as i can tell.

Comment: It is worth pointing out the sometimes not so obvious typos, but if it's a simple typo error, the question should be closed as such.

Comment: yes :D  thanks :D got it :D my pw now look like that : $2y$10$Bumo0vebSvuq77Adizytveky95nn6Jok0VCY8kbRk/xop0QG.SHC6

Comment: can you opvote my question?! then i will be abble to upvote your answear becouse i need 15 points :D to do that

Answer (score 0):

1. Please remove the $hashedPwd so that it will not be include.
2. Your db.php might be the culprit here.
3. Replace PASSWORD_DEFALUT to PASSWORD_DEFAULT as the command for password_hash is being process could not continue but will give null return value.

   ```
   //$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFALUT);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid,user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
   exit();
   ```

Comment: i need tp use it for protection.  i know it will be working with pwd only. i check that ealier